# JQuery animate function only working on first child in a li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following snippet of JQuery is only working on one li item in an ul. When I hover on the other items in the list it won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$("#link").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ color:'#fe57a1'}, 100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: '#fff'}, 300);

});
});
```

The html is as follows:

```
 <div class="col span_6 main-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="link" href="about.php">About</a></li>
                        <li><a id="link" href="soon.php">Place</a></li>
                        <li><a id="link" href="soon.php">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a id="link" href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: put unique attribute of type ID per element, try change id attribute to class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
   <div class="col span_6 main-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="link" href="about.php">About</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link" href="soon.php">Place</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link" href="soon.php">Shop</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link" href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$(".link").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ color:'#fe57a1'}, 100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: '#fff'}, 300);

});
});
```

**You should not use same id for more then one element**

Answer (score 0):

`id`s should only be used once per page. You need to change 'link' to be a class:

`$('.link').`...

`<a class="link">`...

Answer (score 0):

An id (such as your `id="link"` should be unique - there should only be one element with the same id. Try changing these tags to `class="link"` and then using the selector `$(".link").hover` to select all of these elements.

Answer (score 0):

"link" should be the class of the elements not the id. If you have more than 1 element with the same id, JavaScript will only find the first one.